# Trouble optimizing MySQL query containing range expression, order by, and limit

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble optimizing what I think is a reasonable / straightforward query in MySQL. After spending a few late nights on this, I thought I'd post my question here as I'm sure the solution will be obvious to somebody.

Here are the columns in a simplified version of my table T:

- **id:** varchar(32) not null (primary key)
- **timestamp:** bigint(20) unsigned not null
- **family:** char(32) not null
- **size:** bigint(20) unsigned not null

And here's the query that I need to optimize:

```
select
  id
from
  T
where
  family = 'some constant'
and
  timestamp between T1 and T2
order by
  size desc
limit
  5
```

My table is fairly large (~630M rows) so I'm hoping that an index can do most of the work for me... but I'm having trouble picking the right columns for my index.

It seems that in order for MySQL to use an index to answer a range query (like what I'm doing w/ the timestamp), that column must be the last column in the index. But then there's the "order by", which is on a different column. I'm not sure which one of these columns should be last in my index, so I've tried creating the following indices:

- **i1**, on (family, timestamp, size)
- **i2**, on (family, size, timestamp)

... but neither of these seems to help.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

(BTW I'm running MySQL 8 in Amazon RDS, in case that makes a difference.)

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions you may have!

EDIT #1 ---------------------------------------

I just created this simplified table that I described above, and copied 10M rows worth of data from the original table to the simplified table, just to keep things clean. Then I ran the following query:

```
mysql> select
    ->   id, size
    -> from
    ->   T
    -> where
    ->   family = 'be0bf4a203797729f38c6355b6d80903'
    -> and
    ->   timestamp between 1578460425887 and 1584710866343
    -> order by
    ->   size desc;
```

... and took 1.27 seconds. I really need this to be faster, otherwise this sort of query (which I need to run many times per second) will take much too long on the real dataset.

Here are the results of an `EXPLAIN` on the query above:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys             | key                       | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T     | NULL       | range | idx_family_timestamp_size | idx_family_timestamp_size | 136     | NULL | 178324 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

I bet it's the filesort that's killing performance. Any ideas?

EDIT #2 ---------------------------------------

Oops, I just realized that I forgot the `LIMIT` in EDIT #1's query. I've fixed that here, and also grew T to 100M rows -- so now it's 10x the size that it was in my previous edit.

Now my query takes almost 10 sec. to run, and the results of the `EXPLAIN` are as follows:

```
mysql> explain
    -> select
    ->   id, size
    -> from
    ->   T
    -> where
    ->   family = 'be0bf4a203797729f38c6355b6d80903'
    -> and
    ->   timestamp between 1578460425887 and 1584710866343
    -> order by
    ->   size desc
    -> limit
    ->   5;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                       | key                       | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T     | NULL       | range | idx_family_timestamp_size,idx_family_size_timestamp | idx_family_size_timestamp | 144     | NULL | 410744 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index for skip scan; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: it seems trivial to test every combination, but post up the EXPLAIN

Comment: Your `i1` index is correct for this query.  Try running `EXPLAIN`.  If you find that MySQL is not using it, it could have to do with your data.  Either the cardinality is such that the optimizer has decided than an index won't help, or maybe you don't have very much data in your `T` table.

Comment: 630 million of rows sounds like a fair amount of data to me

Comment: @Strawberry and @TimBiegeleisen, I just edited the post to add the results of the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: OK, how unique are the values for family and the timestamp range which appear in the actual query?  Appreciate that if your query would be returning a large chunk of the original table, the optimizer may just choose to go for a scan, and ignore the index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oops, you're right about returning a large chunk of the original table. I forgot to include the `LIMIT` in that query. Sorry about that! Please take a look at EDIT #2. Thanks so much, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: What I said doesn't really change: If the query, minus the limiting step, would be a large portion of the original table, then MySQL might very well just choose to scan and avoid using the index.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. I just did a count, and that query (w/o the limiting step) selects ~800K rows out of a total of 100M rows. Is there any way that I can find out for sure whether MySQL is doing a scan?

Comment: What is the cardinality of family.  If it is low cardinality that is not helpful.  You are getting a filesort, because you order by size, which can not be ordered based on the index used. 
You can't eliminate that.  What happens if you index on timestamp, family?  If you are querying a giant table like this and the result is 400k + rows, there is no magic wand that is going to make that performant.

Comment: There are 58,143 distinct families in T. The total number of rows in T is 10M. So I suppose that counts as low cardinality, right?

Comment: At least in the explains you showed, the index was used.  It shows this in the `key` column.  It also shows the rows being 410k.  Then it has to sort these by size.  Adding size to this index is not helpful with the final sort :(

Comment: That is not low cardinality per se, but compared to the # of rows for a particular range of timestamp it is likely lower.

Comment: The problem with a hypothetical sample is that the actual data matters.  If you truly have a situation where you are going to be generating a 410k result (or larger) then sort that result before you can get a row back, I don't see a way you will make this faster.

Comment: Also, just to understand this, that if you order on something that is not part of the where/join criteria, then it will filesort.  You may want to play with increasing the [sort buffer size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) on the RDS, so that it is more likely your sorts will be in memory.  There's also the innodb buffer pool settings, although in RDS, they have this at a fairly optimal default.  You are using innodb tables i hope?

Comment: Yes, we're using innodb tables!